# How to compose Eclipse CDT projects for C++ codebase with large number of build artifacts

Tags: c++, eclipse, projects-and-solutions, eclipse-cdt

I am using CDT as an IDE for a large C++ codebase that currently uses a recursive Makefile build system, but I'd like to try migrating to Eclipse CDT's internal builder.

The structure of the codebase is that leaf directories generally contain code that is to be linked into a corresponding shared library (e.g. .so file) or executable artifact (e.g. ELF binary). There is an intermediate level of directories that provides some logical grouping, but does not correspond to anything significant in terms of the build or deployment process.

If I were to make one project for each leaf directory, I'd have over 100 projects! Is this even feasible? Is there a better approach?

Some of my team members are hung up on not wanting to go below the logical grouping directory level because the idea of maintaining a large number of projects is intimidating. Is there even a (good) way to group projects in Eclipse CDT?

Comment: Not an answer, but: I recommend against migrating *to* the Eclipse Internal Builder. The internal builder has much less control than custom makefiles. Additionally, the internal builder, while stable and around for a while and quite used, does not have much active maintenance, instead the development effort now is in adding support for cmake.

Comment: @JonahGraham that's helpful, thanks. How mature is the cmake support in Luna, Mars, and Neon CDT?

Comment: The CDT support is currently under development, I expect to see it in future releases. The frameworks for this improvement are already in Neon. Additionally there is http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/cmake-editor which has been around for quite a while and gets good reviews on cdt-dev mailing list.